# Changing Orientation of Tick Marks

Tags: punctuation

I had a question about changing the orientation of an tick mark. For example doing something as so:  'u'

Both are pointing to the left, but for the tick mark on the left side of the object, I want to point inward towards the object, say for instance the alphabet `u` and the tick mark on the right side of the object, I want it to point inwards towards the object, say also the alphabet `u`. I thought I used to know how to do this, but I must of forgot. If anyone needs me to clear up what I am asking, let me know in a comment.

Comment: Do you have an image to embed or link to?  That would help get across what you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: I had previously not understood the question. Here is a second attempt (which I am not very happy with, but it could give inspiration to others).

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{graphics}    
\newcommand{\ticks}[2][3.5pt]{%
  \raisebox{#1}{\rotatebox{20}{\rule{.4pt}{3pt}}}%
  #2%
  \raisebox{#1}{\rotatebox{-20}{\rule{.4pt}{3pt}}}}    
\begin{document}

Is \ticks{u} better? You can raise it for \ticks[5pt]{Capitals}.

\end{document}
```

The idea is that I make a straight line (`\rule`), rotate it, and raise it, to place it at the height you want, by default `3.5pt`.

Comment: @Bruno: Really don't understand your response. But what I was looking for what just straight inverted ticks pointing inwards towards each other say around u.

Comment: @night owl: Sorry I don't see how your description differs from the image.

Comment: @night owl: Are you looking for quotation marks where the ball terminal (thick part) is always at the top and unlike in the image posted here? This would be a matter of finding a font that provides this kind of quotation marks.

Comment: @Christian: Close, but with no ball terminal at all. Just slant (straight) lines or referred to as tick marks, with both slanted inwards towards the object of use. Where is a site or that I can upload a picture or is there a command where I can upload how the description of it looks like?

Comment: @night owl: You can upload images as part of your question or answer using the image button. Conceptually, a quotation mark has always a thick and a thin end. A font might not emphasize this, though. So again, it comes down to find the right font and selecting the right characters but it is not something that can be easily modified, as implied in your question.

Comment: @Christian: Of something just hit me while staring at a ad on the side of the webpage. It looks just like back slashes or forward slashes but of the size of apostrophe. Is that still suffice to having to find the right font to do this? Thanks

Comment: @night owl: is this closer?

Comment: @Bruno: EXACTLY!! THANKS A BUNCH. I knew you were getting close to the solution, hehe. I still don't quite understand all of the syntax like:

    \raisebox{#1}{\rotatebox{20}{\rule{.4pt}{3pt}}}%
      #2%
      \raisebox{#1}{\rotatebox{-20}{\rule{.4pt}{3pt}}}} 

but I am guessing it is a preamble needed to do the raising for the capital letters. I will look into some documentation to get a deeper understanding, but right on point. +1
Thanks again.

Comment: @night owl: I tried to add a short explanation. I don't think this is the "right" solution, though.

Comment: @Bruno: Okay that makes perfect sense in a pictorial way of thinking. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand. It can't be this you mean can it?

```
``foo'' `bar'
```

EDIT: Ah but if mirrored indeed is what you want why not mirror then?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\newcommand{\ticks}[1]{%
      \reflectbox{''}#1''
      }

\begin{document}
    Like \ticks{this}?
\end{document}
```

Or have I still not understood?

Comment: no, that was my first answer, which iI later removed (perhaps I shouldn't have). I think that @"night owl" wants to get a literal \` on one side, and the mirror image on the other side (straight quotes).

Comment: @Bruno: Yes, precisely that, The mirror image of the tick on the left side. See, you understand me. LoL